# Silverlight page with multiple page names in google analytics

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track traffic on my Silverlight page.

The same pages in my app are showing up under different names in the top content page.
For example, I have /Home with the most pageviews, then /ClientBin/???.xap/Home with fewer pageviews and then /Default.aspx/Home with even fewer pageviews.
It's the same with other pages (/ManageUsers, /ClientBin/???.xap/Manageusers, /Default.aspx/Manageusers) and so on.

The pageviews are different, so we can't just add them together since we are not sure why this is happening.

I know you can set a default homepage to account for differences in say / and /index.html, but that does't cover all our cases.

What I need to know is why does this happen? Can we just add them together or are some of them a subset of others?

Some of our users are using Out-of-browser, does that count as one of those three pages or is it mixed in with the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some testing using Fiddler I think I've come to a conclusion.

- The /ClientBin/???.xap/Home and similar pages are from
  Out-of-browser.
- The /Default.aspx/Home and similar pages are from
  when you run the site from Visual Studio (debugging).
- The /Home and similar pages are when the site is accessed on the server.

So in our example we add together the /Home and /ClientBin/???.xap/Home visit numbers to get the real numbers (ignore /Default.aspx/...).